# sbt & Play 2.0 Debugging Information Missing

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am using sbt to build my Play 2.0 project. I managed to configure sbt to open a debugging port, attach an Eclipse remote debugger and enter a break point. I put the break point into one of my actions. But when the execution stops there, I cannot inspect any variable. I guess that sbt builds the Scala code without debugging information.

Does anybody know how to configure sbt to add debugging information? Or could it be a problem of my Scala IDE plugin for Eclipse or anything else?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: are you running Play in development mode?

Comment: Yes, I tried that by putting "application.mode=dev" into my application.conf, but it did not change anything. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: mm run it with "play run" not "play start" or some other command

Comment: mhhh I run it using sbt directly ("sbt run"), not using the play console. In the play console, I could use "debug run", but this is not available when using sbt directly.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think on a solution :(

Answer (score 4):

To start Play in debug mode via `sbt`, run:

```
sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

Comment: That does not work for me: Play 2.0.4, SBT launcher 0.12.1 on Kubuntu. Error messages: Not a valid {command|project ID|configuration|key}: jvm-debug

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and using `sbt` installed via the `apt.typesafe.com` deb repo.  When I run `sbt sbt-version` I get `0.11.3`.  How did you install `sbt`?

Comment: I installed it manually: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#unix

With the deb-Installation it works.

If you install sbt with the .deb file there is a included shell script /usr/share/sbt/sbt-launch-lib.bash that evaluates the param "-jvm-debug". So it could not work for manual installed sbt launcher. That's sad because you could easily use sbt like the gradle wrapper.

Comment: I'll look into this and see if we can get consistency between these.

Comment: I just tried with sbt 0.12.1 (installed from the deb) and the command in my answer still works.  So what is different between our setups?

Comment: The deb version works because of the shell scripts that are installed with it. If you install sbt manually by NOT using any deb-file or repository with only the launcher jar and the minimal shell script from http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#unix it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a solution for all problems I have with debugging but at least it works so that I can use it. Here is my status:

I am using sbt directly and cannot use -jvm-debug 9999. But I added the following to JAVA_OPTS in the sbt launch script: 
`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9999`
This gives the possibility to connect an Eclipse remote debugger and get debugging information (if running Play in development mode).

The problem that still remains is that I don't get the popups showing variable information when pointing the mouse cursor on a variable. But this seems to be a problem with the Scala IDE plugin and not with Play, because I get the variable information in the variables view in the debugging perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the easiest solution : (using IntelliJ IDEA )

in IntelliJ  :

Go to "edit run configurations"

[image]

Create a new remote configuration (port 9999, all other details leave with default values)

[image]

Go back to IntelliJ and run the new debug configuration (don't forget to put a break point)

From command line run :

```
     sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a modularized sbt build. Adding

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-g")
```

to the build.sbt file, solved the problem of missing debug information in the compiled classes.